# JWT vs cookies for token-based authentication

Tags: json, authentication, cookies, jwt

I read some posts about **"JWT vs Cookie"** but they only made me more confused...

1. I want some **clarification**, when people talking about "token-based authentication vs cookies", **cookies** here merely refer to ***session cookies***? My understanding is that **cookie is like a medium**, it can be used to implement a token-based authentication(store something that can identify logged-in user on the **client side**) or a session-based authentication(store a constant on the client side that matches session information on the **server side**)
2. Why do we need **JSON web token**? I was using the standard cookie to implement token-based authentication(**not using session id, not use server memory or file storage**): `Set-Cookie: user=innocent; preferred-color=azure`, and the only difference that I observed is that JWT contains both **payload and signature**...whereas you can choose between **signed or plaintext** cookie for http header. In my opinion signed cookie (`cookie:'time=s%3A1464743488946.WvSJxbCspOG3aiGi4zCMMR9yBdvS%2B6Ob2f3OG6%2FYCJM'`) is more space efficient, the only drawback is that client cannot read the token, only the server can...but I think it's fine because just like *claim* in JWT is optional, it's not necessary for token to be meaningful

Comment: Hi, I noticed you asked this question 7 years ago. I have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444165/confusion-about-cookie-authentication-vs-token-authentication-what-is-the-diffe , just not JWT in particular but I am quite confused about session control. Maybe you can take a look. I would like know if you have gained more insight all these years.

Answer (score 290):

The biggest difference between bearer tokens and cookies is that the browser will ***automatically send cookies***, where bearer tokens need to be added explicitly to the HTTP request.

This feature makes cookies a good way to secure websites, where a user logs in and navigates between pages using links.

The browser automatically sending cookies also has a big downside, which is [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks. In a CSRF attack, a malicious website takes advantage of the fact that your browser will automatically attach authentication cookies to requests to that domain and tricks your browser into executing a request.

Suppose the web site at https://www.example.com allows authenticated users to change their passwords by `POST`-ing the new password to https://www.example.com/changepassword without requiring the username or old password to be posted.

If you are still logged in to that website when you visit a malicious website which loads a page in your browser that triggers a POST to that address, your browser will faithfully attach the authentication cookies, allowing the attacker to change your password.

Cookies can also be used to protect web services, but nowadays bearer tokens are used most often. If you use cookies to protect your web service, that service needs to live on the domain for which the authentication cookies are set, as the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) won't send cookies to another domain.

Also, cookies make it more difficult for non-browser based applications (like mobile to tablet apps) to consume your API.

Comment: "If you are still logged in to that website when you visit a malicious website which loads a page in your browser that triggers a POST to that address, your browser will faithfully attach the authentication cookies, allowing the attacker to change your password."

Doesn't CORS prevent this?

Comment: @kbuilds Only is the malicious page is using AJAX to POST the form. If the attacker gets you to click the submit button on a regular form, CORS does not come into play.

Comment: but doesn't this mean that the site would only be vulnerable if there were no CSRF tokens being used?

Comment: Right, you can mitigate CSRF attacks by using CSRF tokens. But this is something you have to do explicitly.

Comment: using cookies protects you from XSS attacks, however to be able to set the Authorization header, you need to access the access token from javascript; it's easy to protect yourself from CSRF, but XSS is much harder to protect against- Bearer tokens are more meaningful, but it comes with a price

Comment: so this means that JWT can only be used for AJAX requests? or does the browser automatically add the token for non-Ajax request?

Comment: @Andy The browser does not automatically add JWTs to requests. You'll need to do this programmatically in JavaScript. Technically, you could stick the JWT in a query parameter on a hyperlink to your service, but that increases the chances of your JWT inadvertently being logged somewhere.

Comment: It's worthwhile to mention that the Set-Cookie's SameSite attribute can effectively prevent CSRF attacks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

And since browsers now use `SameSite=Lax` as a default value and if you do not make changes on GET requests, you are protected by default. However only in case of modern browsers. `SameSite=Strict` is even a more robust variant.

A good article to read: https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/same-site-cookie-attribute-prevent-cross-site-request-forgery/

Comment: @kataik Cookies DON'T protect against XSS attacks. Http Only Cookies aren't vulnerable to XSS attacks. You still need to add XSS protection.

Comment: @MvdD my question is then where to store JWT tokens? if I store it in localStorage it can be accessible through "malicious" web by javascript, storing in memory also doesn't look the best option, but as I investigated found that the safest would place to store is cookies because they are not accessible with JS. However you said that cookies will be attached automatically to request, so it is also not safe if JWT be stored in a cookie?

Comment: @kbuilds CORS does not stop cross origin requests, it's the same origin policy that does that. CORS is NOT a security feature, it's an insecurity feature. Using CORS literally makes your website less secure, but with the benefit of allowing certain cross site requests.

Comment: CSRF tokens are important - Steam (2021) doesn't use CSRF tokens with its cookies.. my brother had all his rocket-league gear stolen by a guy in Russia, when he clicked on a pretty legit looking steam "profile" link that someone sent him, and had his session stolen. lol. Sure enough the fake profile page had cookie snagging js...

Comment: @MvdD Hi, Sending cookie automatically is one obvious difference. What about session control? Can token-based authentication do session control? Why do people always refer to cookie authentication when they talk about session control?

Comment: `In a CSRF attack, a malicious website takes advantage of the fact that your browser will automatically attach authentication cookies to requests to that domain and tricks your browser into executing a request.` contradicts what you say further down: `the same-origin policy won't send cookies to another domain.`

Answer (score 198):

## Overview

What you're asking for is the difference between cookies and bearer tokens for sending JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) from the client to the server.

Both cookies and bearer tokens send data.

One difference is that cookies are for sending and storing arbitrary data, whereas bearer tokens are specifically for sending authorization data.

That data is often encoded as a JWT.

## [Cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

A cookie is a name-value pair, that is stored in a web browser, and that has an expiry date and associated domain.

We store cookies in a web browser either with JavaScript or with an HTTP Response header.

```
document.cookie = 'my_cookie_name=my_cookie_value'   // JavaScript
Set-Cookie: my_cookie_name=my_cookie_value           // HTTP Response Header
```

The web browser automatically sends cookies with every request to the cookie's domain.

```
GET http://www.bigfont.ca
Cookie: my_cookie_name=my_cookie_value               // HTTP Request Header
```

## [Bearer Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)

A bearer token is a value that goes into the `Authorization` header of any HTTP Request. It is not automatically stored anywhere, it has no expiry date, and no associated domain. It's just a value. We manually store that value in our clients and manually add that value to the HTTP Authorization header.

```
GET http://www.bigfont.ca
Authorization: Bearer my_bearer_token_value          // HTTP Request Header
```

## [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) and Token Based Authentication

When we do token-based authentication, such as OpenID, OAuth, or OpenID Connect, we receive an access_token (and sometimes id_token) from a trusted authority. Usually we want to store it and send it along with HTTP Requests for protected resources. How do we do that?

Option 1 is to store the token(s) in a cookie. This handles storage and also automatically sends the token(s) to the server in the `Cookie` header of each request. The server then parses the cookie, checks the token(s), and responds accordingly.

Option 2 is to store the token in local/session storage, and then manually set the `Authorization` header of each request. In this case, the server reads the header and proceeds just like with a cookie.

It's worth reading the linked RFCs to learn more.

Comment: is it safe to store sensitive data into local/session storage? or it's just whatever since tokens are ephemeral?

Comment: Once the app server receives the ID token (which contains claims), then does it send that token to the browser? So that subsequent api calla can pass that id token to allow app server to know who has invoked the endpoint.

Comment: In `Option 2` is session storage not the same as cookie? What does session storage refer to?

Comment: @Gezim One important difference: the browser automatically sends cookies with _all_ requests to their domain; the browser does not do that with session storage. Another important, related difference: many browsers block cookies to avoid tracking; the browsers tend not to block session/local storage, because they have less use for tracking.

Comment: You cannot use the Set-Cookie header when doing an HTTP request in the browser. You must use document.cookie for that, the browser will automatically add HttpOnly cookies to the request before sending it.

Comment: *A cookie is a name-value pair, that is stored in a web browser*, I thought that cookies were stored on the local machine by the browser and sent by the browser. They are not **stored in** the browser.

Comment: what about XSS attack and jwt is exposed ?

Answer (score 42):

In addition to what MvdD has said about cookies being automatically sent:

1. A cookie can be a medium, but its most significant function is how it interacts with the browser. Cookies are set by the server and sent in requests in very specific ways. JWT on the other hand is exclusively a medium, it is an assertion of some facts in a particular structure. If you were so inclined, you could put a JWT as your authentication cookie. When you read articles comparing them, they typically are talking about using a JWT sent as a bearer token by front end code vs an authentication cookie which corresponds to some cached session or user data on the back end.
2. JWT offers many features, and puts them in a standard so they can be used between parties. A JWT can act as a signed assertion of some facts in many different places. A cookie, no matter what data you put in it or if you sign it, only really makes sense to use between a browser and a specific back end. JWT can be used from browser to back end, between back ends controlled by different parties (OpenId Connect is an example), or within back end services of one party. Regarding your specific example of your signed cookies, you can probably achieve the same functions ("not using session id, not use server memory or file storage") as JWT in that use case, but you lose out on libraries and peer-review of the standard, in addition to the CSRF issues talked about in the other answer.

In summary: the posts you're reading are probably comparing JWT as a bearer token to authentication cookie for browser to server authentication purposes. But JWT can do much more, it brings in standardization and features for use outside the use case you're probably thinking of.

Comment: Good job clarifying that the comparison is really between Bearer tokens and cookies.

Answer (score 37):

While cookies can increase the risk of CSRF attacks by virtue of them being sent *automatically* along with requests, they can decrease the risk of XSS attacks when the `HttpOnly` flag is set, because any script that is injected into the page won't be able to read the cookie.

CSRF: a user clicks on a link (or views images) on an attacker's site, which causes the browser to send a request to the victim's site.  If the victim uses cookies, the browser will automatically include the cookie in the request, and if the GET request can cause any non-read-only actions, the victim site is vulnerable to the attack.

XSS: an attacker embeds a script in the victim site (the victim site is only vulnerable if inputs are not sanitized correctly), and the attacker's script can do anything JavaScript is allowed to do on the page.  If you store JWT tokens in local storage, the attacker's script could read those tokens, and also send those tokens to a server they control.  If you use cookies with the `HttpOnly` flag, the attacker's script won't be able to read your cookie to begin with.  That said, the script they successfully injected will still be able to do anything JavaScript can do, so you're still hosed IMO (i.e., while they may not be able to read the cookie to send it off to their own server for use later, they *can* send requests to the victim site using XHR, which will include the cookie anyway).

Comment: is there any solution to not allow the attacker get your JWT through localStorage or by sending a cookie with JWT in itself?

Comment: @DignityDignity You can store a JWT in localstorage or a cookie (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38470665/237182)); my answer is just to mention that cookie vs bearer token is a trade off (cookies can be more secure in one sense, and less secure in another)

Comment: CSRF is almost impossible because the default value of sameSite is lax.

Answer (score 28):

#### Cookies

In case of cookies, once the user has been authenticated then the Gmail Server will create a unique session Id. Corresponding to this session id it will store in memory all the user information that is needed by the Gmail server for recognizing the user and allowing it perform operations. 
Also then for all subsequent requests and response, this session id will also be passed. So now when the server receives a request it will check the session id. Using this session id will check if there is any corresponding information. It will then allow the user to access the resource and return back the response along with the session id.

[image]

#### Drawbacks of Cookies

- Cookies/session id is not self contained. It is a reference token. During each validation the Gmail server needs to fetch the information corresponding to it.
- Not suitable for microservices architecture involving multiple API's and servers

[image]

#### JWT

- JWT is self contained. It is a value token. So during each validation the Gmail server does not needs to fetch the information corresponding to it.
- It is digitally signed so if any one modifies it the server will know about it
- It is most suitable for Microservices Architecture
- It has other advantages like specifying the expiration time.

[image]

Reposted from my Blog Post - [Need for JSON Web Token](https://www.javainuse.com/webseries/spring-security-jwt/chap1)

Comment: If the user clicks “log me out of all sessions”, then with each request the token must be validated by a database call - so the idea that it is self-contained doesn’t hold. Short expiries might help but it’s not perfect.

Comment: How would Google Drive know the secret key used in the Gmail service to validate the JWT token?

Comment: @Amit Gmail and Google Drive would share the same secret key

Comment: Use short expirations on JWT access tokens and use JWT refresh tokens with long expirations that are stored in the database and can be revoked. The client, upon getting a 401 or deciding it's time to refresh, calls into the refresh endpoint using the refresh token to receive a new access token and new refresh token pair. The server then revokes the refresh token passed in to prevent it from being used again. Access tokens are used for access to secure resources. Refresh tokens only have claims to create new token pairs but are also associated with the user id so a password is not required

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, cookies can be used for anything.
2. Why do we need JWT?

JSON is the best (and only needed IMHO) data format in which you can put anything you want.

With JWT you are not limited by the size of your data, with cookies you only have 4093 bytes per domain - for all cookies, not the one.

Despite the above, I would implement JWT authentication using cookies. I.e. generate JWT access token and store it in a cookie.

Comment: No please don't store the JWT access token in a cookie. It's best to store it in session storage since storing it in a cookie make it prone to XSS attacks, and an Httponly cookie is still vulnerable to CSRF attacks.